# Acessar Arquivo Database File, SYBASE

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, banco-de-dados, sybase

Estou precisando retirar os dados de um arquivo database file (.db) que me disseram que é SYBASE, o cliente necessita fazer migração de dados e preciso acessar, alguém faz ideia por onde começar? pois nunca ouvir falar de sybase.

Lembrando que não é um servidor, é um ARQUIVO.

Queria acessa-lo via C#.

Comment: Você sabe ao menos o nome e a senha da base? Você já tentou algo?

Comment: Poderia por favor postar o código que tem até o momento?

Comment: Então, não sei nem por onde começar e não tenho senha da base, e é um arquivo.